# Using multiprocessing module with BaseHTTPRequestHandler

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, httpserver

I'm trying to use the python multiprocessing module to run a server in another Thread using the http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler module. I am stuck though and am running into a '_thread.lock' issue.

I don't want to use the threading module because I'd rather use true multi-threading with the multi-processing module.

If anyone knows what I am doing incorrectly or can point me to a good library to use that would be awesome.

```
import multiprocessing
from http.server import ThreadingHTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

if __name__ == '__main__':
  httpd = ThreadingHTTPServer(('localhost', 4433), BaseHTTPRequestHandler)

  manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
  manager.http_server = httpd
  running_server = multiprocessing.Process(target=manager.http_server.serve_forever)
  running_server.start()
```

Stack Trace:

```
File "/Users/redacted/python/test2/test1.py", line 10, in <module>
    running_server.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 284, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(process_obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 47, in _launch
    reduction.dump(process_obj, fp)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python uses pickle to pass objects to another process when using multiprocess module. In your case, the thread lock used in the httpserver is not pickleable. So it reports the error.
What you can do is start the http server in another process completely like this:

```py
import multiprocessing
from http.server import ThreadingHTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

def startServer():
    httpd = ThreadingHTTPServer(('localhost', 4433), BaseHTTPRequestHandler)
    httpd.serve_forever()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
  manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
  running_server = multiprocessing.Process(target=startServer)
  running_server.start()
```

Also, you might want to try a different port other than 4433. I cannot connect to this port on my windows machine. But if I use 8000 everything works fine.